# Disable SortExpression for specific Column on a Dynamically created GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridView table (using ASP.NET 3.5)` that is populated using a `SqlDataSource` object (from my SQL DB), that changes dynamically from different SELECT Command, according to different Authorization rules (more/fewer information is retrieved).

In GridView I have set `AllowSorting=true` and it's working perfectly.

**my problem is:**
I want to `disable Sorting` for specific Columns (E.g. Photo), and I understand it's done by setting:

```
myGrid.Columns[i].SortExpression = "";
```

Only, when I'm trying to access this specific column, I'm getting the error of:
**`Index Out Of Bound (column doesn't exist yet!).**

I tried connecting to the following events:

- RowDataBound
- RowataBinding

and it still did not work.
How can I access the specific column (once it's dynamically created) and disable it's sorting?

**Here is Snippet:**

`ASPX Page:`

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridNew" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" EnableModelValidation="True">
```

`.CS Page:`

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gridNew.DataSourceID = "Employees_DataSource";
        switch (ddlSelection.SelectedValue)
        {
            case "Admin":
                Employees_DataSource.SelectCommand = @"SELECT * FROM [Employees]";
                gridNew.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = true;
                gridNew.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;
                gridNew.DataBind();
                //gridNew.Columns[1].SortExpression = "";
                // This is not working!! :(
                break;

            case "Manager": ...

            default:
                break;
        }
```

Thanks! :)
Mitsy.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable sorting on any column (including dynamic) by disabling the cell on the GridView DataBound event. This will give the desired result of disabling the column's header from appearing as a button.

```
protected void yourgrid_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yourgrid.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Enabled = false;
    yourgrid.HeaderRow.Cells[5].Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Matt this is just the answer I was looking for.  I fill GridView from DataTable and have no boundfields or templatecolumns.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle the [`GridView.Sorting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx) event. The [`GridViewSortingEventArgs.SortExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewsorteventargs.sortexpression.aspx) is writable.

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    // replace with your logic
    String newOrder = "Column1";
    e.SortExpression = newOrder;
    e.SortDirection = "DESC";
}
```

**Edit**: If you just want to disable sorting for a specific column in an event, normally it should work to set the `GridViewColumn`'s `SortExpression` to `null`:

```
GridView1.Columns[0].SortExpression = null;
```

However, you are using a SqlDataSource(which i'm not familiar with and personally avoid) **and** you've created your `GridView` dynamically. Is also the GridView's RowCollection empty? Are you recreating your dynamic GridView(s) on every postback with the same ID as before in Page_Load at the latest?

Comment: Hi! by doing your solution, and disabling the Sorting logic, I don't actually *disable* the column's Header from appearing as a button ("sortable"), and only causing it remain clickable, but do nothing. any idea how I can actually prevent it from appearing as a button? (like a label).

Comment: @user1268741: edited my answer. You should show how and where you're creating the grid dynamically.

Comment: The columns are created dynamically using the SqlDataSource object. It works perfectly, my only problem is with the Sorting. any other solutions? :\